# Rails Has Many Through Source Association Not Found Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, relational-database

I'm currently trying to implement a favorite function in my rails application. But when I try to click the add to favorite link I recieve the error message:

Could not find the source association(s) :favorite or :favorites in model FavoriteEvent. Try 'has_many :favorites, :through => :favorite_events, :source => '. Is it one of :event or :user?

My attempt is as follows:

**Event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :favorite_events
    has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_events, source: :user
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    has_many :favorite_events
    has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_events
end
```

**Favorite_event.rb**

```
class FavoriteEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event
end
```

**event_controller**

```
def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "add"
        current_user.favorites << @event
    else
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Event not added'
    end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to "Add to calendar",   
    favorite_event_path(@event, type: "favorite"),
    method: :put %>
```

**Route**

```
resources :events do
    put :favorite, on :member
end
```

Comment: All your classes are named 'Event'? User belongs_to user? Seems you have a lot of typos there, please clean up your code samples, that's extremely confusing.

Comment: @thorstenmüller Wow. Sorry about that. I was very tired and manually entering everything. I have edited everything to reflect how it should be. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :favorite_events
    has_many :events
    has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_events, source: :event
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model structure should be like this.

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    has_many :favorite_events
    has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_events
end
```

**favorite_event.rb**

```
class FavoriteEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event
end
```

This shows that: A User has_many Events
and a User has_many favorite_event through event.

I think that You wanted to implement.
Am i right @adanot ?

Comment: I have edited my question. I accidentally had a lot of mistakes and typos initially.